# Floor function identity for $[\sqrt{n^2-n}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

From my textbook, where [n] is the greatest integer less than or equal to n.

> Since $n^2-n=(n-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$, it follows, $[\sqrt{n^2-n}]=n-1$

This one feels like a great leap, I really don't see it at all and it doesn't feel like the kind of question where I can say "I tried doing ..."

Comment: Can you see why $\sqrt{n^2-n}<n$ and $\sqrt{n^2-n}\geq n-1$ (assuming $n$ is a positive integer)?

Comment: @user10354138 Yep I get it that way. For personal closure could you try shed some light on what they were going for? Throw all of it into an answer and i'll accept it if you will

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the unique integer $n$ satisfying $n \le x < n+1$. From $n-1 \le \sqrt{n^2-n} < n$, it follows that $\left\lfloor \sqrt{n^2-n} \right\rfloor = n-1$.

Comment: Maybe they were hinting that since $n^2 - n$ is just "a little" less than $(n-\frac{1}{2})^2$, then $\sqrt{n^2-n}$ is just a little less than $n - \frac{1}{2}$, so its floor must be $n - 1$.  Of course, there's more work needed beyond what they said to make it precise that "a little" less is still close enough to get a floor of $n-1$.

Comment: That said, it *would* be a useful heuristic method to *guess* what the simpler expression should be, and then you can use the other method from the hints in the other comments to verify that that expression is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a joke in the mathematical community that the phrase "it follows" doesn't necessarily give any indication of how elementary the implication is.  Ideally, an author has an appropriate sense of their audience when they say that, but sometimes it takes a wall of algebra to justify a conclusion that an established mathematician would regard as "obvious".  As you grow as a student, you will find your sense of obviousness will expand.

In this case, one presumes that $n$ is positive integer.  Then

$$(n-1)^2=n^2-2n+1\le n^2-n<n^2$$

and since every expression there is positive we can take the square root of everything to get

$$n-1\le\sqrt{n^2-n}<n$$

And the stated implication follows immediately from the definition of the greatest integer function.

---

What was the author going for with the statement they cited?  I suppose they were saying that $\sqrt{n^2-n}\approx n-\frac12$ as $n$ becomes large.  Frankly, I don't think that's a particularly strong argument since you don't how *a priori* how the square root behaves before $n$ becomes large, but one assumes that it is "obvious" to the author.